# how to pass a string argument that contains white space?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a program that takes string as an argument, such as

```
$ ./say "hello world"
```

and would like to invoke this program from roslaunch.

Here is an example of the launch file:

When I check the command line argument with

```
$ roslaunch say.launch --args /say
</pre>
the output is
<pre>
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src /home/k-okada/ros/diamondback/say/say "hello world" __name:=say
</pre>
and this is ok to me.
but when I try to start this program from launch file by
<pre>
$ roslaunch say.launch
```

the argument corrupts. It seems that the roslaunch divide string arugment into each words as written in the log file

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2011-07-01 13:35:10,808: process[hoge-1]: args[[u'/home/k-okad
a/ros/diamondback/say/say', '"hello', 'world"', u'__name:=
say']]
```

Changing the launch file to

worked, but if there are other solution, I would like to know that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10454/how-to-pass-a-string-argument-that-contains-white-space?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The args string is interpreted by shlex, which uses the POSIX command-line parsing rules.  Thus, the arg string should be identical to whatever you would have typed in a shell.

I did a test on my own setup and the following works:

```
args='"hello world"'
```

or

```
args='"hello world'"
```

i.e. you don't need to escape the quotes.

The reason why the --args works is that the terminal does not represent separate arguments, and roslaunch simply prints back the arguments to the screen with a space separator.  I could attempt to escape --args so that it preserved the argument separation, though this would have the side-effect of making the output of --args harder to read.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-07-01**:
thanks, this works for me too.